# Python regex freezes with small input string

Tags: python, regex, freeze

I am using regular expressions on a bunch of wikipedia pages. Actually working really good for the first like 20 pages, but then it suddenly freezes without me seeing a reason. Interrupting the script delivers this:

```
File "imageListFiller.py", line 30, in getImage
foundImage = re.search(urlRegex, str(decodedLine))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/re.py",line 173, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

this is my code:

```
def getImage(wikiHtml):  
    urlRegex = """File:((?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))*?\.(png|jpg|svg|JPG))"""
uselessPictures = ("Wiktionary-logo-v2.svg", "Disambig_gray.svg",
                   "Question_book-new.svg", "Commons-logo.png")    

for line in wikiHtml:
    decodedLine = line.decode('utf-8')
    foundImage = re.search(urlRegex, str(decodedLine))
    if foundImage:
        if not foundImage.group(1) in uselessPictures:
            return foundImage.group(1)
```

and this is the input string that causes it to freeze:

> href="/wiki/File:EARTH_-_WIKIPEDIA_SPOKEN_ARTICLE_(Part_01).ogg" title="Listen to this article"> src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Sound-icon.svg/20px-Sound-icon.svg.png" width="20" height="15" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Sound-icon.svg/30px-Sound-icon.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Sound-icon.svg/40px-Sound-icon.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="128" data-file-height="96" > />

The regex is not actually supposed to match here, it just needs to skip this line.
Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI: Note that `[$-_]` matches all uppercase ASCII letters and digits, and more. If you escape the hyphen, it will already be much safer.

Comment: You (or better your expression) is prone to catastrophic backtracking: https://regex101.com/r/eH4nJ2/1

Comment: why not simply `([^/]*\.(png|jpg|svg|JPG))`

Answer (score 1):

The `$-_` part in your pattern created a range matching uppercase letters and digits, and even more chars. Since other alternative branches in the group could match at the same location (like `[a-zA-Z]`) that led to a time out / catastrophic backtracking issue.

You need to just concat all the character classes that only match 1 char in the 1st group, and either escape the `-` inside the character class or put it at the start/end of the character class (I'd still escape it if the pattern is going to be updated in the future):

```
r"""File:((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9\-$_@.&+!*(),])*?\.(png|jpg|svg|JPG))"""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF2vH8/3).

Also, the longer alternative should precede the shorter one, so the `[0-9a-fA-F]{2}` should go first.

Also, `\w` can be used to shorten the pattern a bit (to replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

```
r"""File:((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[\w\-$@.&+!*(),])*?\.(png|jpg|svg|JPG))"""
                             ^^^
```